# Is there a way to connect external databases to R to extract the data

Tags: r

“Is there a way to connect external databases to R to extract the data. Say, I have a database called Aziz(Name changed). In Aziz, I have 100 lots of databases in the form of excel or csv. Can I extract any one of the them into R? ”

Comment: yes: https://db.rstudio.com/

Comment: if excel use `read_excel()` from `readxl` package, if csv use `read_csv` from `readr` or `read.csv` from `base` R. use `?read_excel` or `?read_csv` to read documentation and see examples. If you know what type of DB you have, you can connect to it directly using the DBI package : here's an overview https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Databases.html